# SQL Agent - Can I delete an intermediate job step without consequences?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-agent-job, sql-agent

Say I have a job in SQL Server with 8 steps.

If I run a script to delete an intermediate job step, like such:

`EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_jobstep @job_id=N'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx', @step_id=5`

What happens? Will the job run as scheduled, and just skip from step 4 to step 6? Will the job break?

Comment: You need to be careful about the triggering of the next job.  That depends on how your jobs are set up.

Comment: Why not use the GUI instead? One of the few times I'd suggest that actually you're better off

Comment: @William; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Every Step in Steps tab have two property :

1. On success action
2. On failure action

check these, there is no problem with deleting steps if you handle that.